# Importing data to a Mac

Tags: r

I am on a Mac so I am not sure what the library files look like as on Windows. I need to import a csv dataframe into R but I keep getting the error that no such file exists. I have tried these two things:

```html
read.table("c:/data.csv")

source("c:/data.csv")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is not much to go on in that post but it sounds like you need to set your working directory (the place where r is looking for the data).

You can see your current working directory with the getwd() function and you can change it with the setwd() function.

If that is all set correctly, read.table() might work.  I'm not that familiar with that function but source() is for loading functions into r.  You might also try read_csv() from the readr package in the tidyverse.

Hope that helps.